# What does it mean in Chrome's dev tools when a js file's link starts with debugger?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

I'm trying to diagnose a JavaScript issue in an ASP.Net website that I didn't write. I've loaded Google Chrome's development tools and run the function that isn't working and am getting an error that says:

> Uncaught TypeError: jQuery.clean is not a function

When I click on the error in the debugger it is showing me a file which is obviously knockout.js. I believe the issue is that we have upgraded jQuery to a new version that no longer contains the .clean function. This much isn't that interesting just background to my question.

I'm trying to figure out where Chrome has got knockout.js from so that I can upgrade it. However when I look at the location of the knockout.js file it is telling me it has come from `debugger:///VM830`. That is clearly not part of the site. I have tried right clicking on 'Empty Cache and Hard Reload' but it is still showing as coming from the same place. My question is what is the `debugger:///VM830` location and where might it actually come from?

Comment: Debugger should be a script of the chrome js engine... and debugger:///VM830 a basic shortcut to call it ( it seems that works like eval(XXX) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like our "quality" code is downloading knockout.js as an XHR request and then executing the response using `eval()`.